# Using puppeteer to upload an input[type=file] from a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, puppeteer

I'm building a tool that lets people upload a file to me, and then I post that file to multiple other websites.

I'm using puppeteer to post this information to each of the other websites.

I need to upload this file to each of these other websites via a HTML file upload box.

To save the user from having to wait through uploading their file to multiple different websites, I want to upload the file to some storage service (e.g. S3, Blob Storage etc) and then send the URL from the storage service to the file upload box. This allows the user to quit out of the app as soon as they've uploaded their file has finished uploading to my storage service.

Is this possible? My attempt of

```
    const fileUploadHandle = (await page.$(
      "span#add_files1 > input[type=file]"
    )) as ElementHandle<HTMLInputElement>;
    await fileUploadHandle.uploadFile(filePath); // filePath is the URL from the storage service
```

doesn't work.

If not possible, what is the best way to build this functionality?

Comment: AFAIK, puppeteer does not support upload file using remote url. You have to download a local copy then upload using puppeteer again.

Comment: That would be a good solution. Thank you